# HOW Check Url Parametr and Redirect with Nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I want to check if a parameter is present in a url in nginx and then rewrite.

How can i do that?

For e.g if url is http://website.com/search/node/item123/loc=33 then redirect to http://website.com/search/node/item123

my code is here and not work !

> if ($arg_loc != "") {
> rewrite ^(/search/.*)$ $1? permanent;
> }

**UPDATE :**
i want redirect any url that ends with **loc=number** to the parent url ! for arabic and enlgish characters

EG :

```
http://website.com/search/node/item123/loc=33
```

i want redirect to

```
http://website.com/search/node/item123/
```

or

```
http://website.com/search/node/عربیک/loc=55
```

should be :

```
http://website.com/search/node/عربیک
```

Comment: Your example URL has no query arguments, therefore your `if` code cannot work.

Comment: Are you sure there's no question mark in the first URL?

Comment: No Bro !! any question mark

Comment: Please clarify your issue. Does the URL you want to redirect contain query arguments or not? If it has query arguments, then your `if` approach is correct. If not, then you need to match on the URL path.

Comment: In that case it's no a  parameter, but a some weird URL.

Comment: UPDATED QUESTION !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no query parameters in your examples. It's just an url, so you could use `rewrite`.

Something like that:

```
rewrite "^(/search/node/[^/]+)/loc=\d+$" $1 permanent;
```

P.S. I would strongly recommend to use keyword `redirect` instead of `permanent` until you're 1000% sure that redirect works as it should.

Comment: How can i use keyword redirect instead of permanent ?

Comment: @BijanZand, what do you mean? Just put `redirect` instead of `permanent`. This will do 302 redirect instead of 301. The problem with `permanent` is, well, it's permanent and if you make a mistake you'll have hard time to remove that permanent redirect from your browser.

Comment: @BijanZand well `\d` stand for *digits*. You'll need `\w` or `[a-z0-9]` I guess. Anyway, make yourself familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: i see your update man , but for mix character Arabic  & English character **\w+** not working !
do you have a solution?

Comment: @BijanZand you really should have been mention all these conditions in original question. I've updated answer.

Comment: work like charm man...thanks